# Datepicker for LaTeX fillable form

Tags: forms, interaction

I am replicating a fillable/savable form from LiveCycle with LaTeX using `\CheckBox` and `\TextField` items. I would also like to replicate the pop-up calendar / datepicker feature. I am aware of the `insDLJS` package which sounds like I could program one in JS, but does anyone know of a simpler method?

Comment: Can you provide an MWE of related functionality? I'm not familiar with a lot of the stuff you're talking about.

Comment: The forms are generated using the `hyperref` package. The date picker is essentially a text field which when clicked opens a calendar / date picker; the selection is then entered as a formatted date in the text box. I am asking whether I need to learn JS to program one through `insDLJS` or if there are alternatives?

Comment: I understand what the final result is; I do not understand how to get it (text boxes, check boxes, etc.) up and going. I've never had the need to create such a PDF. Please provide a MWE.

Comment: ... maybe a look at the package will help ... [datepicker-pro on CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/datepicker-pro?lang=de)

Comment: That's good, though there was a fair amount of lag for me... using the date pickers in the manual.

Comment: From Ctan: `This package has become obsolete as of December 2020. Since December 2020, Adobe no longer supports Flash player`…

Comment: Even with Adobe support it was broken by design to rely on Flash player, imho.

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/488757/2388 there is an inbuilt date picker in recent adobe reader. The answer show how to use it with hyperref, so here as an alternative the code for l3pdffield-testphase. Notice that the javascript need an additional parentheses pair.

```
\DocumentMetadata{}
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{l3pdffield-testphase}


\begin{document}
Pick up a date:
 \ExplSyntaxOn 
 \pdffield_textfield:n
  {
   name      =mydate, 
   format    ={(AFDate_FormatEx("dd.mm.yyyy");)},
   keystroke ={(AFDate_KeystrokeEx("dd.mm.yyyy");)}
  } 
 \ExplSyntaxOff 


\end{document}
```

[image]