# How do you create a date field with hyperref's pdf forms?

Tags: hyperref, forms, javascript

Some PDF readers might support a date picker for a text field that contains a date format, as explained here: [How to create datepicker using JavaScript in Acrobat DC Pro?](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2266102)

This article gave me the impression that I have to format the `\TextField` from `hyperref` for dates. Currently I've no idea how to achieve this. I've tried to figure out which properties of the text field I need to change in JavaScript with the help of [Acrobat DC SDK Documentation](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/acrobat/acrobat_dc_sdk/2015/HTMLHelp/), but I can't find anything that works. Perhaps I've missed something.

Does anyone know how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This needs javascript and if I got your link right a recent adobe reader.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{Form}
\TextField[format   ={AFDate_FormatEx("dd.mm.yyyy");},
           keystroke={AFDate_KeystrokeEx("dd.mm.yyyy");}]{date}
\end{Form}

\end{document}
```

[image]